# Apache file system does not respond my AJAX request

Tags: javascript, html, ajax, apache, webserver

I've written some java script that sends an AJAX request to get the HTML page in my computer and display on the screen.

But, every time I made changes on the HTML file like adding more div, picture or some simple text. The server (localhost) always response me back an old version of the HTML file.It looks like I haven't made any change to the HTML file (but actually I did).

**For example, if this is the old HTML file.**

```
<div class="login">
    <form name="login_form" method="post" action="#">  
    </form>
</div>
```

**After I made some changes**

```
<div class="login_123245">
        <form name="login_form" method="post" action="#">  
               <input type="submit" name="btn_submit" value="submit"/>
        </form>
</div>
```

**Here's the javascript code**

```
function getHTMLPage(directory) {
    xmlHttp.open("GET","http://localhost/NewWorkspace/webProject_01/"+directory);
    xmlHttp.onreadystatechange = function () {
        if (xmlHttp.readyState == 4) {
            if (xmlHttp.status == 200) {
                //return xmlHttp.responseText;
                html_Page = xmlHttp.responseText;
                show_response_page2(html_Page);
            }
        }
    };
    xmlHttp.send();
}
```

***show_response_page*** is the function that returns the requested HTML page.

I also found a way to solve this which is not so good solution.
Every time I want to make changes to HTML file, I need to create a new HTML file and change its name which is not so inconvenient for me.

Please help.

Comment: try EnableSendfile off and EnableMMAP off in httpd.conf?

Comment: Thanks, it works after I removed hash sign and turn on to both of them

Comment: No, seriously, it not working again

Comment: Seems to me to be a caching issue, try deactivating the browser's cache and check in your debug console if the file is serverd from cache.